# Doxygen/sphinx and forward-declared enum class

Tags: c++, c++17, python-sphinx, doxygen

I have such code in a C++17 header file to forward-declare enums and functions:

```
 /**
   * @enum Code
   *
   * The Code enum is the actual place to define CORSIKA 8 particle codes.
   */
  enum class Code : int32_t;

  /**
   * @enum PDGCode
   *
   * Specifically for PDG ids.
   */
  enum class PDGCode : int32_t;

  typedef std::underlying_type<Code>::type CodeIntType;
  typedef std::underlying_type<PDGCode>::type PDGCodeIntType;


  int16_t constexpr get_charge_number(Code const);
```

and then subsequently in related files the `Code` and `PDGCode` enums are filled with content and the `get_charge_number` function is implemented.

This works perfectly fine in C++17. But doxygen always complains with a WARNING, which I am not able to fix or work-around:

```
Running Sphinx v3.5.3

WARNING: Error when parsing function declaration.
If the function has no return type:                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  Error in declarator or parameters-and-qualifiers                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  Invalid C++ declaration: Expected identifier in nested name, got keyword: enum [error at 4]                                                                                                                                                                   
    enum PDGCode int32_t typedef std::underlying_type< Code >::type CodeIntType typedef std::underlying_type< PDGCode >::type PDGCodeIntType constexpr int16_t get_charge_number (Code const)                                                                   
    ----^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
If the function has a return type:                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  Error in declarator or parameters-and-qualifiers                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  If pointer to member declarator:                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    Invalid C++ declaration: Expected '::' in pointer to member (function). [error at 21]                                                                                                                                                                       
      enum PDGCode int32_t typedef std::underlying_type< Code >::type CodeIntType typedef std::underlying_type< PDGCode >::type PDGCodeIntType constexpr int16_t get_charge_number (Code const)                                                                 
      ---------------------^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  If declarator-id:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    Invalid C++ declaration: Expecting "(" in parameters-and-qualifiers. [error at 21]                                                                                                                                                                          
      enum PDGCode int32_t typedef std::underlying_type< Code >::type CodeIntType typedef std::underlying_type< PDGCode >::type PDGCodeIntType constexpr int16_t get_charge_number (Code const)                                                                 
      ---------------------^
```

It seems doxygen or sphinx cannot parse the valid C++ of the forward declaration of the `enum class`. It mixes things together. Is there a way to fix this? I don't like such warnings.... they make it impossible to find real problems.

**EDITs**

- this is doxygen version 1.8.17, which comes with Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: When running the doxygen 1.9.2 version I do see some problems. 1) it looks like the `@enum` dpes not recognize `enum class` by setting the `@enum` to `@class` it looks like this problem can be overcome. 2) the syntax of the `enum class`  does not look like to be understood by doxygen. This will be a bit harder to overcome. For documentation purposes it looks like moving the the definitions to the end does solve the problem. These are of course all workarounds, best is to create an issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new?template=report-a-bug-or-issue.md

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful for me and the workaround actually helps.

Comment: Still it would be good to create an issue, so inn future you (and others) don't have to use a workaround.

Comment: A bit of lack of knowledge on my side, but shouldn't the line `enum class Code : int32_t;` read `enum class Code : int32_t{};` from the standard (2020 version, paragraph: 9.7.1 Enumeration declarations) I get that the {} are mandatory: `enum-specifier:
enum-head { enumerator-listopt }
enum-head { enumerator-list , }`. For a `class` I can find a reference to a forward declaration but not for an `enum class`. When using the `{}` doxygen parses the code properly (in the 1.8.17 version the word class get lost but in the 1.9.2 version it is present so there might be some problems with 1.8.17).

Comment: Looks like that the standard is having a "forward declaration" and calling it `opaque-enum-declaration`: `opaque-enum-declaration:
enum-key attribute-specifier-seqopt enum-head-name enum-baseopt ;`

Comment: Despite a missing issue: I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 8888, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8888).

Comment: The mentioned pull request has been integrated into the master version on github.